# How to configure code - coverage for Zend framework 2.4 with PHPUnit version 8.5.1?

Tags: zend-framework2, php-7.2, phpunit

How to configure code - coverage for Zend framework 2.4 with PHPUnit version 8.5.1 ?

Any documentation, article or blog to refer to with working example ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I found out the issue, my phpunit of zendframework was old (version 6.x)
Gone to the project folder executed composer update via.

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^8
```

Checked the version via.

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --version
```

Once upgraded, opened below files and made mentioned changes:

- File: **vendor/zendframework/zendxml/tests/ZendXmlTest/SecurityTest.php** check for "**class SecurityTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase**" and change it to "**class SecurityTest extends TestCase**" and add namespace "**use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;**"
- File: **vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php** check for "abstract class AbstractControllerTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase" and change it to "**abstract class AbstractControllerTestCase extends TestCase**" and add namespace "**use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;**"

After the above changes, my phpunit was ready for the first sample ApplicationControllerTest, created the test file with help of below link:
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.test.phpunit.html

And executed the same using below regular command:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit [FILEPATH]
```

Worked for me, maybe it might help someone too!